# "Permission denied" error when using "fopen" function in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, fopen, ubuntu-15.10

I have the following code, and I run it from localhost:

```
def create_names_file(req, names, data, profileid):
    s = names
    fname = str(profileid)
    fpath = req.conf["inf_path"]+"/"+fname
    f = open(fpath, 'w')
```

`req.conf["inf_path"]` is `/opt/fp/trunk/analysis/2/`, and I receive permission error.I use Ubuntu OS. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Run your script as `root` maybe can solve this.

Comment: Actually I'm running on localhost.

Comment: I know, do you have an user on your OS called `root`? or you can use command `sudo python your_script_name.py` instead of `python your_script_name.py`.

Comment: I open localhost url from browser. There should be a different solution for that. It is so weird

Comment: @yusuf, you simply don't have permissions to read the file, what does `ls -l` on the file output? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Then you could change the permission of `fpath`...whatever,  take a look at [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Step By Step Guide: 4.11. Ownership and Permissions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html) maybe can give you some ideas.

Comment: @KevinGuan, how would opening a directory give you a permissions error? You would get `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:`

Comment: Yes Kevin, I want to do that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Wait, my bad. The `fpath` actually is `req.conf["inf_path"]+"/"+fname`.  And the directory actually is `req.conf["inf_path"]` . (I've edited the question to clarify it.)

Comment: @yusuf, you need to add the full permissions to your question, if you don't want to run the script with sudo you will have to give your user read permissions on the file

Comment: I have tried to do that, but I couldn't manage Padraic. Could you give me a little help?

Comment: @yusuf, add what `ls -l your_file` outputs on the file, obviously replacing the your_file with the full path to the file

Comment: the output is "total 0"

Comment: How can I do it Padraic? :)

Comment: You can `sudo chown username folder` then `sudo chmod u+rw folder`, that will change the owner of the dir to username, then the second command gives that user read and write permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to open a file named `/opt/fp/trunk/analysis/2/` which in invalid due to the trailing slash. Possibly that is a typo so, if the required file already exists, who owns it?

Does the user that you run Python as have permissions to write to that file?

Check the permissions reported by `ls -l  /opt/fp/trunk/analysis/2`.

Comment: the output is "total 0"

Comment: Then `/opt/fp/trunk/analysis/2` represents an empty directory. So, unless you intending to open the directory file itself, there is nothing to open. Also, you don't have permission to open the directory, You can check the permissions for that with `ls -ld /opt/fp/trunk/analysis/2`.